# Can I observe question not asked by me

Tags: support

Is there a way to mark questions in which I do not parcitipate as observed so when anything changes in observed topic I gen notified by inbox in top left corner?

Comment: There is a new feature which can be used for this purpose - see [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994#31406) and [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). A few pointers to some useful information can be found [in the corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can - by clicking the little star to the left of the question, you mark it as a "favorite". [More details are provided here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work).

The notifications it provides are [displayed on the "StackExchange" logo on the upper left of the site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/).

However, it appears that the [notifications are temporarily broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates/52094#52094). When they come back online, marking a question as one of your "favorites" will do what you want.