# A way to "watch" questions?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications, follow-post

I apologize if this has come up before on meta, because it almost certainly has, but I couldn't find it.

I frequently come across recently asked unanswered questions that I find interesting. However, I haven't been able to find a satisfactory way to watch such questions for answers. The best I've come up with is adding it to my favorites or simply leaving a tab open in my browser and refreshing it periodically.

This is in contrast to when I ask questions. I am immediately informed of answers or comments.

Is there way to set a notification to trigger when a question is answered? Does anyone have better techniques for monitoring interesting questions?

Comment: See also: [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted)

Answer (score 13):

Every question has an associated RSS feed. While I'm not 100% certain that all comments appear on that feed, the answers certainly do.

Comment: This is a rather clunky solution.

Comment: Is there a FAQ somewhere on how to use RSS feeds?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: On the web generally, certainly there are such, eg. see the Wikipedia article.  I copied the link at lower right corner of this page "question feed" and added it to [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#overview-page) using the Subscribe button there (pasting the URL into the popup).

Comment: Based the failure of that reader to pick up my comment above, it does seem Questions and Answers, but not Comments are included in the feed, per Asaf's post above.

Answer (score 10):

Just added today... the "follow" feature.

> [image: follow]

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble comprehending what those pop-ups were trying to tell me! I think I get it now that I see your image.

Comment: The announcement on [meta.se]: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). (It also mentions that there is a pland to created a separate tab for followed posts in the user's profile.)

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: All possibilities mentioned here are superseded by possibility to [follow posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info) implemented in April 2019. It is described [in another answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/a-way-to-watch-questions/31406#31406).

The original version of the answer (before this was implemented) is below.

---

Let us try to summarize several possibilities how to follow question, which are mentioned  in various answers and comments on this site:

- One possibility is to use [favorites](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/favorites/info). You would have to check favorites tab to see whether there is something new. Changes to favorite questions are [highlighted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/what-does-highlighting-mean-on-the-profiles-favorites-tab), if you sort your favorites by last activity (most recent). AFAIK it is not shown what exactly are the changes, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes). I don't know which changes cause highlighting, but posting new answer definitely does and from my experience I suspect the also posting comments and editing the question do.
- Questions have [RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34481/subscribe-to-others-questions/34491#34491) as mentioned in another answer to this question and also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted/4868#4868).
- On StackApps you can find [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](https://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites). This was mentioned in a comment [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/is-there-a-way-to-follow-a-question#comment63751_17225)
- Also on StackApps you can find [StackTracker - Cross-platform desktop notification app](https://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app). It was mentioned [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/is-it-possible-to-add-a-question-to-the-watchlist/9587#9587).

Comment: I have made the post CW. Feel free to edit the answer, add other ways to follow questions, add further details, clarifications, useful links.