# Is it possible to add a question to the watchlist?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to add a question to a kind of a watchlist in order to get notifications when e.g. there is a new answer or a new comment posted there? I would like to use this, for example, for a question to which I haven't contributed yet, but would be interested in saving it as a "bookmark", possibly to post an answer or comment later when I will have time, or to see if there will be any further discussions.

I was experimenting with marking such questions as "favourite" but it does not look very efficient; moreover, it does not look like the intended use of favourites since it likely distorts the MSE statistics. OTOH, I've discovered recently that each question page has a "question feed", but if I'd like to keep an open eye on several questions, I have to set up my RSS feed reader for each feed separately. IMHO, having an aggregated feed may be interesting as well.

Thanks for any suggestions and/or workarounds!

Comment: Similar question/feature request: [Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks - then my question looks like a duplicate of the one from your link (except that the StackTracker is mentioned only here). BTW, as it is said [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/add-notify-option), Mathoverflow has "Notify" option (which I did not test).

Comment: You wrote: * it does not look like the intended use of favourites since it likely distorts the MSE statistics.*
You can read more about favorites [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work), I believe that this is precisely what favorites are intended for. 
IMO, if some functionality is implemented and available for users, the users can use it how they see fit and they don't have to worry about things site statistics.

Comment: @MartinSleziak - thanks, that's useful.

Comment: An option to follow posts was implemented in 2020.
See also: [the corresponding tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info), [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994) and [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661)

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing built in besides the two ways you already know. You may be interested in [StackTracker](https://stackapps.com/questions/290/stacktracker-cross-platform-desktop-notification-app):

> StackTracker, a cross-platform desktop notifier for the StackExchange API built with PyQt4
>
> The application displays a task tray notification when someone has posted an answer or a comment to a question you are tracking on any of the StackExchange sites. Clicking the notification will open the corresponding question in your browser.

Caveat emptor: I did not test this myself.

Comment: thanks for confirming that there is nothing else built-in and for the link to the StackTracker. The [StackTracker project](https://github.com/swanson/stacktracker/) seems to be inactive for a while so I would probably wait till hopefully someone could confirm that it still works.