# Can I follow a question?

Tags: support

Sometimes I see a question that is interesting, but I can't answer it or comment on it.  Is there any way for me to mark it so that I can find it again later and see if there were any answers or comments?

Comment: See MSO faq on [Favorite questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/214632).

Comment: Now there is a new feature which can be used to follow posts. See: [the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info), [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) and [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994)

Answer (score 4):

Just click the star below the downvote button. The question will then appear among the favorites in your [profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/93354/mitchell-kaplan?tab=favorites).

Comment: Now there is a new feature which can be used to follow posts. See: [the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info), [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) and [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994)