# Is there a way to follow a question?

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

I often see questions on math.stackexchange.com that I would like to follow.  That is, I would be notified if there is any activity on the question so that I can see the answers that are provided.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This question is inappropriate outside of meta. The answer is the star below the downvote.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work

Read that for all the details.

Comment: Clicking on the 'star' favorites the qeustion and you get notifications, although it seems to notify you about lots of activities, like comments.

Comment: You may be interested in [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](http://stackapps.com/questions/4454/stackeye-chrome-extension-to-follow-users-and-questions-on-stackexchange-sites).

Comment: Related older questions: 
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4978/new-answer-posted-notification-for-answerers
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/a-way-to-watch-questions
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/add-notify-option
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/is-it-possible-to-add-a-question-to-the-watchlist

Comment: Recently a feature doing this was implemented: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). This is also mentioned in this answer: [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994#31406)