# Being aware of changes in some question or answer

Tags: support, notifications

> Is there a way to be aware of changes in some question or answer of someone else?

I mean when changes happen I receive  a note in my inbox, like my own questions.

thank you

Comment: Try marking the question as a [favorite](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171723).

Comment: You can find several older similar discussions, like [A way to “watch” questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/a-way-to-watch-questions),
[Can I follow a question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/can-i-follow-a-question),
[Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted) (and other related questions). You might also browse other questions tagged ([meta-tag:notifications]) or ([meta-tag:favorites]).

Comment: Now there is a new feature which can be used to follow posts. See: [the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/follow-post/info), [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) and [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994)