# I want to be notified when a question is answered

Tags: support, answers, notifications

Sometimes I like a question but I don't want to keep that page open for all eternity. Is there a way to make sure I get notified when the question is answered?

Comment: [Favourite the question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work) You'll have to check yourself from time to time in your profile whether some of your favourite questions got updated, and if so which, but you don't need to keep the tab open.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88468/what-is-the-best-way-to-be-notified-when-a-specific-question-not-my-own-is-ans - Unanswered.

Comment: I'll do it. Send me your name, address, and telephone number.

Comment: You can use the question's RSS feed, the link to which is at the bottom right: e.g.,  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/feeds/question/20539 is the feed of this question. Of course, you'd need another tool that can notify you of new items in the feed.

Comment: Yet another option is  [StackEye](http://stackapps.com/q/4454/26164), a Chrome extension.

Comment: I will simply copy my comment from [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17225/is-there-a-way-to-follow-a-question#comment63752_17225). Related older questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4978/ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6994/ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8804/ http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9585/

Comment: Recently a new feature related to this was implemented, see: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) and [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994#31406)